# How can I order the results as they are inserted into a HSQLDB table?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

When I run the following script using HSQLDB, I get the error message `user lacks privilege or object not found: T2C1`. How can I order the rows as they are inserted into table `TABLE3`? Can I achieve this goal without adding another table?

Note that if I comment the line `ORDER BY "T2C1", "T1C2"`, I won't get any error messages but `TABLE3` won't get sorted either.

```
DROP TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" IF EXISTS;

CREATE TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" (
  "C1" VARCHAR(10),
  "C2" VARCHAR(10),
  "C3" VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" ("C1", "C2", "C3") VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c');
INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" ("C1", "C2", "C3") VALUES ('d', 'e', 'f');

DROP TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" IF EXISTS;

CREATE TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" (
  "C1" VARCHAR(10),
  "C2" VARCHAR(10),
);

INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" ("C1", "C2") VALUES ('a', 'b');
INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" ("C1", "C2") VALUES ('u', 'v');

DROP TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE3" IF EXISTS;

CREATE TABLE "PUBLIC"."TABLE3" (
  "C1" VARCHAR(10),
  "C2" VARCHAR(10),
);

INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."TABLE3" (
  "C1",
  "C2"
)
SELECT 
(SELECT
"T2"."C1" AS "T2C1"
FROM "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" "T2"
WHERE "T2"."C1" = "T1"."C1"),
"T1"."C2" AS "T1C2"
FROM "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" "T1"
ORDER BY "T2C1", "T1C2"
;

* *DSV_COL_DELIM=,
* *DSV_ROW_DELIM=\n
* *DSV_TARGET_FILE=results.csv

\x "PUBLIC"."TABLE3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HSQLDB 2.2.x supports use of ORDER BY here. The problem with your SELECT is the lack of column alias T2C1 for the scalar subquery. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."TABLE3" (
  "C1",
  "C2"
)
SELECT 
(SELECT
"T2"."C1" AS "T2C1"
FROM "PUBLIC"."TABLE2" "T2"
WHERE "T2"."C1" = "T1"."C1") AS T2C1,
"T1"."C2" AS "T1C2"
FROM "PUBLIC"."TABLE1" "T1"
ORDER BY "T2C1", "T1C2"
;
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make too much sense for me since the order of inserts are irrelevant as others already have mentioned on various forums:

- http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1617505-insert-into-order.html
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/aeb1053d-0dc2-4dc3-96f5-8b213fed9669

I think HSQLDB just gives a wrong error message. It doesn't work with MSSQL.